# json_encode retornando TAGS HTML

Tags: php, html, ajax, json

Ao realizar `echo json_encode($data);`, estou a receber ,via `console.debug(data)`, o seguinte:

```
<br />
<font size='1'><table class='xdebug-error xe-notice' dir='ltr' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1'>
<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan="5"><span style='background-color: #cc0000; color: #fce94f; font-size: x-large;'>( ! )</span> Notice: Undefined variable: v_prod_total in C:\wamp64\www\nfe\admin\nfephp-master\exemplos\NFe\4.00testaMakeNFe.php on line <i>464</i></th></tr>
<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#e9b96e' colspan='5'>Call Stack</th></tr>
<tr><th align='center' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>#</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Time</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Memory</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Function</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Location</th></tr>
<tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>1</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0020</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>424896</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>{main}(  )</td><td title='C:\wamp64\www\nfe\admin\nfephp-master\exemplos\NFe\4.00testaMakeNFe.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>...\4.00testaMakeNFe.php<b>:
```

O que pode estar acontecendo?

Script:

```
$http({
          method  : 'POST',
          url     : 'enviar.php',
          dataType: 'json',
          data : dados: dados ,
          headers : {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
         })
         .success(function(data) {
            if (data.errors) {
              $scope.erroValidar = "Erro";
            } else {
              $scope.key = data.chave;
              console.debug(data);
            }
          })
```

Obs.: o json_encode esta entre uma "infinidade" de código em PHP

```
try{
        $query = $conecta->prepare('SELECT * FROM empresas WHERE situacao=1');
        $query->execute();
        $resultado = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }catch (PDOexception $erro){
        echo 'Erro ao selecionar: '.$erro->getMessage();
    }

    foreach($resultado as $res){
        $razao_social_emt   = $res['cidade'];
        $nome_fantasia_emt  = $res['nome_fantasia'];
        $cnpj_emt           = $res['cnpj'];
        $insc_estadual_emt  = $res['insc_estadual'];
        $logradouro_emt     = $res['logradouro'];
        $numero_emt         = $res['numero'];
.
.
.
echo json_encode($data);
.
.
.
else {
    header('Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
    foreach ($nfe->erros as $err) {
        echo 'tag: &lt;'.$err['tag'].'&gt; ---- '.$err['desc'].'<br>';
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: o json_encode não esta retornando uma string contendo a representação JSON dos valores.

Comment: do tipo: {"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seu código está retornando uma mensagem de erro:

A variável `v_prod_total` não está definida.

No arquivo: C:\wamp64\www\nfe\admin\nfephp-master\exemplos\NFe\4.00testaMakeNFe.php

Linha: 464

Além desta, cheque se há outras variáveis não definidas.

Se forem numéricas e estiverem em loop, coloque os valores das mesmas antes do loop com o valor inicial igual a ZERO.

Comment: Só um instante @AllanAndrade, vou verificar.

Comment: Posso criar um chat pra te explicar alguns detalhes?

Comment: Pode sim. Tranquilo.

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51455/json-encode-retornando-tags-html

Answer (score 2):

Deixa eu traduzir o que aconteceu:

1 - Esse HTML aí com essa classe `x-debug` não me é estranho. Você provavelmente está usando a extensão Xdebug no PHP.

2 - Esse HTML só aparece quando tem erro.

3 - Há um erro. Ele é `Notice: Undefined variable: v_prod_total`. Você está tentando acessar uma variável que não foi definida.

4 - O problema não é função `json_encode`. Se você resolver o erro, o retorno `JSON` ficará correto (se não tiver outro erro, é claro).

Comment: O x-debug está desabilitado: `[xdebug]
zend_extension ="c:/wamp64/bin/php/php5.6.25/zend_ext/php_xdebug-2.4.1-5.6-vc11-x86_64.dll"
xdebug.remote_enable = off
xdebug.profiler_enable = off
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = off
xdebug.profiler_output_name = cachegrind.out.%t.%p
xdebug.profiler_output_dir ="c:/wamp64/tmp"
xdebug.show_local_vars=0`

Comment: Já corrigi o valor de `v_prod_total`.

Comment: Seguindo o conselho do @nottherealhemingway, agora o seguinte erro é apresentado no console: `angular.min.js:117 SyntaxError: Unexpected token A in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>) at wc (angular.min.js:17) at dc (angular.min.js:91) at angular.min.js:92 at q (angular.min.js:7) at gd (angular.min.js:92)`

Answer (score 1):

Eu uso os seguintes cabeçalhos para retornar JSON:

```
<?php

// No topo da página
header("Access-Control-Allow-Orgin: *"); // CORS
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: *"); // Verbos HTTP[S]: PATCH, PUT, DELETE, GET, POST
header("Content-Type: application/json");
```

Outra coisa é que seu código está lendo a condição passada no IF e retornando o que está em ELSE, que contém um cabeçalho (header) que retorna HTML. Esse HTML está simplesmente formatando a mensagem de erro gerada pela linha 464 (4.00testaMakeNFe.php).

Você pode gerar o erro de outra forma:

```
.
.
.
else {
    // Remove o cabeçalho
    foreach ($nfe->erros as $err) {
        errors[] = $err;
    }
    echo json_encode($err, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
}
```

Comment: Realizei as modificações @nottherealhemingway, agora o seguinte erro é apresentado no console:

`angular.min.js:117 SyntaxError: Unexpected token A in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at wc (angular.min.js:17)
    at dc (angular.min.js:91)
    at angular.min.js:92
    at q (angular.min.js:7)
    at gd (angular.min.js:92)`

Comment: Por favor, não use o trecho de código para marcar coisas como PHP ou códigos que não são executáveis dentro do site, o uso do `Trecho de código` (Stack Snippet) é executar CSS, HTML e JS. PHP não roda dentro do site. Para colocar PHP use o `Amostra de código` (ou pelo Atalho Ctrl+K). Leia para entender melhor: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/4463/3635

Comment: tudo bem. É que eu estava preocupado em solucionar um problema.

Answer (score 0):

Com a ajuda do @AllanAndrade, via chat, conseguimos descobrir que o problema estava nas `variáveis não inicializadas` e na `chamada de outras funções/bibliotecas que estavam utilizando print_r, var_dump e echo`.